# Sprite Sheets Pygame/Python

Tags: python, pygame, sprite

So I am making a game in pygame and really need to get sprite sheets working.  Every sprite sheet example I've seen however, is either terrible and I have no idea how to use it or is not a class.  I thought that by pressing in the direction of the arrow keys(which is the movement in my game) I could just draw it to the player objects x and y values.  This works for the first arrow key and if you press another after that it errors with

> TypeError: argument 1 must be pygame.Surface, not bool

My code is:

```
posi=[player.rect.x,player.rect.y]

if left1:
        posi=[player.rect.x,player.rect.y]
        screen.blit(left,posi)

    if right1:
        posi=[player.rect.x,player.rect.y]
        screen.blit(right,posi)

    if down1:
        posi=[player.rect.x,player.rect.y]
        screen.blit(down,posi)

    if up1:
        posi=[player.rect.x,player.rect.y]
        screen.blit(up,posi)
```

and I pretty much set left1,down1,right1 or up1 equal to true if you press an arrow key

Comment: Look into [Pyganim](http://inventwithpython.com/pyganim/).

Comment: It would be create if you could provide us the full error message and fix the indent of your code...  :)

Comment: Looks good, double check for typos

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are not using `screen.blit` correctly. The first argument should be the image you are blitting (in other words, the picture of the sprite) and the second argument should be a tuple coordinate.

Go into your code and check what `left` is: I bet that it is not an image, so substitute it with the sprite's image. The coordinates are fine, though.

Pygame docs (see for help with surfaces): [pygame home](http://www.pygame.org)